# Android Studio movement emulation not working as expected

Tags: java, android, user-interface, robotics, joystick

Can anyone tell me why my movement class x, y, and theta values are showing the values expected. But when it's emulated/run the 'nib' is mirroring all the movements instead of being right under the touch point. I don't want to change the math for the values if I don't have to, I just need to have the view show the same thing that the math is saying.

```
public class MovementDial extends AppCompatImageView {

  public float x, y, r, Radius, _theta, xShift, yShift, offset;
    private double distance, distanceAdj;
    private RectF _knobRect = new RectF();
    private PointF nibCenter, touchPoint;
    private RectF nibRect = new RectF();

    OnAngleChangedListener _angleChangedListener = null;


    public interface OnAngleChangedListener {
        void onAngleChanged(float theta);
    }

    public MovementDial(Context context) {
        super(context);
        nibCenter = new PointF(_knobRect.centerX(), _knobRect.centerY());
    }

    public float getTheta() {
        return _theta;

    }

    public void setTheta (float theta){
        _theta = theta;
        invalidate();
    }


    public void setOnAngleChangedListener(OnAngleChangedListener listener) {
        _angleChangedListener = listener;
    }

    private int map(double x, double in_min, double in_max, double out_min, double out_max) //@author: Aaron Pabst
    {
        int mapVal = (int) ((int)(x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min);
        return mapVal;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

        yShift = e.getY();
        xShift = e.getX();

        touchPoint = new PointF();

        touchPoint.x = (int)(e.getX() -  _knobRect.centerX());
        touchPoint.y = map(yShift,0,(_knobRect.height()-_knobRect.centerY()),(_knobRect.height()-_knobRect.centerY()), 0);

        x = touchPoint.x;
        y = touchPoint.y;

        float theta = mapThetaCoords(x,y);  //maps out theta values between 0 to 360 using a traditional unit circle layout.

        setTheta(theta);

        double Radian = Math.toRadians(_theta);
        final double PIValue = Math.PI/180;

         Log.i("Touch", "initial Xvalue is :" +touchPoint.x);
         Log.i("Touch", "initial Yvalue is :" +touchPoint.y);
         Log.i ("Touch", "Touch point 3 changed to: " + theta);

         distance = (float) Math.hypot(x, y); //polar coordinate radius (r = sqrt x^2 + y^2)

        if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Log.i("Touch", "Xvalue touch is :" +touchPoint.x);
            Log.i("Touch", "Yvalue touch is :" +touchPoint.y);
            Log.i ("Touch", "Touch point 6 changed to: " + theta);
            if(yShift == Radian)

        if(distance <= Radius) {

            nibCenter.x = _knobRect.centerX() - (float)(Radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta)));
            nibCenter.y = _knobRect.centerY() - (float)(Radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)));

            x = touchPoint.x;
            y = touchPoint.y;

            Log.i("Touch", "Xvalue touch2 is :" +touchPoint.x);
            Log.i("Touch", "Yvalue touch2 is :" +touchPoint.y);
            Log.i("Touch", "Xvalue nib2 touch is :" +nibCenter.x);
            Log.i("Touch", "Yvalue nib2 touch is :" +nibCenter.y);

        } else if(distance > Radius) {


            Log.i("Touch", "Xvalue touch3 is :" +touchPoint.x);
            Log.i("Touch", "Yvalue touch3 is :" +touchPoint.y);

            nibCenter.x = _knobRect.centerX() - (float)(Radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta))); 
            nibCenter.y = _knobRect.centerY() - (float)(Radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta))); 

            x = touchPoint.x;
            y = touchPoint.y;

            Log.i("Touch", "Xvalue nib1 touch is :" +nibCenter.x);
            Log.i("Touch", "Yvalue nib1 touch is :" +nibCenter.y);


            }
            invalidate();
            return true;


        } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            Log.i("Touch", "Xvalue2 move is :" + touchPoint.x);
            Log.i("Touch", "Yvalue2 move is :" + touchPoint.y);
            Log.i ("Touch", "Move value point 7 changed to: " + theta);

            distanceAdj = distance;
            distance = Math.min(distance, distanceAdj); //comparing changing polar radius values as coordinates change place.

            if(distance <= Radius) {    //check to see if polar radius coordinate is less or equal to the radius value

                nibCenter.x = _knobRect.centerX() - (float)(distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta))); 
                nibCenter.y = _knobRect.centerY() - (float)(distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta))); 

                x = touchPoint.x;
                y = touchPoint.y;
                Log.i("Touch", "Xvalue move1 is :" + x);


            } else if (distance > Radius){

                Log.i("Touch", "Yvalue (greater than) move is :" + y);

                nibCenter.x = _knobRect.centerX() - (float)(distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta) - 360)); 
                nibCenter.y = _knobRect.centerY() - (float)(distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta) - 360)); 

                x = touchPoint.x;
                y = touchPoint.y;
                Log.i("Touch", "Xvalue move2 is :" + x);
                Log.i("Touch", "Yvalue move2 is :" + y);

            }
            invalidate();
            return true;

        } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            reset();
        }

        return false; 
    }
    public float mapThetaCoords(float x, float y) {

        double atan2 = Math.atan2(y , x);
        float theta;

        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0) {             // Q 1
            theta = (float) Math.toDegrees(atan2);
            return theta;

        } else if (x < 0 && y > 0) {       // Q 2
            theta = (float)  Math.toDegrees(atan2);
            return theta;
        } else if (x < 0 && y < 0) {        // Q 3
            theta = (float) Math.toDegrees(atan2) + 360;
            return theta;

        } else if (x > 0 && y < 0) {        // Q 4
            theta = (float) Math.toDegrees(atan2) + 360;
            return theta;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void reset(){
       x = _knobRect.centerX()-(_knobRect.width()/2);
       y = _knobRect.centerY()-(_knobRect.height()/2);
       nibCenter.x = x;
       nibCenter.y = y + _knobRect.centerY();
       _theta = 0f;
       distance = 0f;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        _knobRect.left = getPaddingLeft();
        _knobRect.top = getPaddingTop();
        _knobRect.right = getWidth()- getPaddingRight();
        _knobRect.bottom = _knobRect.width();

        offset = (getHeight() - _knobRect.height()) * 0.5f;
        _knobRect.top += offset;
        _knobRect.bottom += offset;


        Radius = _knobRect.width() * 0.35f;

        nibCenter.x = x + _knobRect.centerX();
        nibCenter.y = y + _knobRect.centerY();


        float nibRadius = Radius * 0.2f;


        nibRect.left = nibCenter.x - nibRadius;
        nibRect.top = nibCenter.y - nibRadius;
        nibRect.right = nibCenter.x + nibRadius;
        nibRect.bottom = nibCenter.y + nibRadius;


        Paint knobPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        knobPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Paint nibPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        nibPaint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);

        canvas.drawOval(_knobRect, knobPaint);
        canvas.drawOval(nibRect, nibPaint);

    }
```

Comment: Debug your code and find exactly where the math is wrong or an unexpected value shows.

Comment: I have been. The best place I can guess I am causing it to mirror, is within the map method. However, this method is what is allowing me to have the movement method match a standard unit circle values.

Comment: But don't guess, know...